# How do I install sprockets in middleman?

Tags: ruby, middleman

Im reading the middloeman-sprockets githud guide, and in configuration, they dont say exactly what to do, they dont say where or how i should run that code...

All they have is this here: https://github.com/middleman/middleman-sprockets

```
Configuration

activate :sprockets
```

here do i add that in the gem file? in the console, where else ?

i tried it in the console but it says:

```
command not found
```

can anyone exaplain ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activate :sprockets` goes into your `config.rb`.

But Middleman comes with Sprockets out of the box, so you don't have to do anything.